# How to create user portion of access token for high-trust app?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to get an on-premise, provider-hosted application to be logged-in when the user is logged into SharePoint, and logged out when the user logs out of SharePoint, so essentially a "federated identity" scenario.  This is a "high-trust" app.

I had thought that I could basically setup my application to use the Windows Identity Framework and have SharePoint communicate the user via claims authentication (something along the lines of [How To: Build Claims-Aware ASP.NET MVC Web Application Using WIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061.aspx)

However, I cannot get that to work.  After some further digging, I found [How to: Create high-trust apps for SharePoint 2013 using the server-to-server protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179901.aspx)  Among other things, it states:

- "The server-to-server STS ***isn't*** intended for user authentication."
- "In a high-trust app, there **is no context token**, even if you use the appredirect.aspx file"
- "If you’re using a high-trust configuration, *your web application has to authenticate the user in the same way that SharePoint 2013 does* (that is, **the app is responsible for creating the user portion of the access token**)"

How can I authentic my provider-hosted appmodel web application "in the same way that SharePoint 2013 does" and create the "user portion of the access token"?

Comment: It is looking like I may have to create my own trusted identity provider to get this scenario to work.